# Call def and change Qt and variable based on passed value

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

In the example below I would need to do this function about 7 times. The only change would be instead of `strength` it would be `perception` for example. Anywhere you see the word `strength`, it would need to be changed, including in the Qt functions such as `self.strengthSpin.setValue()`.

Is there a way to do this without copying/pasting the code several times?

```
if stat == "strength":
    newValue = self.strengthSpin.value()
    varChange = newValue - strength
    if varChange > 0:
        if statPoints - varChange >= 0:
            statPoints -= varChange
            self.statPointsLCD.setProperty("intValue", statPoints)
            strength += varChange
            self.strengthSpin.setValue(strength)
        else:
            print("not enough stat points")
            self.strengthSpin.setValue(strength)
    else:
        if newValue > 0:
            print("should be adding")
            statPoints -= varChange
            self.statPointsLCD.setProperty("intValue", statPoints)
            strength += varChange
            self.strengthSpin.setValue(strength)
        else:
            print("must be at least 0")
            self.strengthSpin.setValue(strength)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you will have to save `strength` and `statPoints` as attributes of `self' (or pass them to method and later return them from it):

```
def update_value(self, name):  # name is 'strength'
    spin = getattr(self, name + 'Spin')
    newValue = spin.value()
    oldValue = getattr(self, name)
    varChange = newValue - oldValue
    if varChange > 0:
        if self.statPoints - varChange >= 0:
            self.statPoints -= varChange  # if this variable should be different for different names, use setattr instead
            self.statPointsLCD.setProperty("intValue", statPoints)
            setattr(self, name, newValue)
            spin.setValue(newValue)
        else:
            print("not enough stat points")
            spin.setValue(oldValue)
    else:
        if newValue > 0:
            print("should be adding")
            self.statPoints -= varChange
            self.statPointsLCD.setProperty("intValue", statPoints)
            setattr(self, name, newValue)
            spin.setValue(newValue)
        else:
            print("must be at least 0")
            spin.setValue(oldValue)
```